# What does Utility usually means?

Tags: architecture

May be it is a dumb question but I have seen "Utility" Classes in a lot of softwares. What do they usually do? Why are they named "Utility"? When should I use the name? Is Mathf a Utility class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Helper classes. For example, you may have imported a `Geometry` class that has a set of polygons. Suppose you want to compute in multiple places throughout your code, say, number of intersections between polygons, or the bounding box of the entire geometry. For small things like that it makes no sense to subclass `Geometry`, so you create either a class or a namespace `GeomUtils` that has static functions to compute the things about `Geometry` that you want, and then you use `GeomUtill::ComputeIntersections` or `GeomUtils::ComputeBBox` when needed. Basically a collection or small related functions that you want to keep in the same place.